# Groovy enum protect properties

Tags: groovy, enums

In java I will normally setup an `enum` as follows

```
public enum MealType {

  BREAKFAST("Breakfast"),
  LUNCH("Lunch"),
  DINNER_OPEN("Dinner Cafeteria Open"),
  DINNER_CLOSED("Dinner Cafeteria Closed");

  private String label;

  private MealType(String label) {
    this.label = label;
  }

  public String getLabel() {
    return label;
  }
}
```

This works out nice because now my enum has a nice human readable label and that label is unchangeable under normal circumstances. For example I cannot do: `MealType.BREAKFAST.label = "fred"`

However when I try to do the same thing in Groovy, the getters and setters are automatically generated. Now I have undesired methods created.  `MealType.BREAKFAST.label = "fred"` would result in the enum label being changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare the label as `final` to prevent a setter being generated:

```
enum MealType {
  BREAKFAST("Breakfast"),
  LUNCH("Lunch"),
  DINNER_OPEN("Dinner Cafeteria Open"),
  DINNER_CLOSED("Dinner Cafeteria Closed");

  final String label;

  MealType(String label) {
    this.label = label;
  }
}
```